# Contract termination after applying for Extension of Period of Stay in Japan

Tags: working-visas, japan

My visa will expire at the start of next February, I applied for Extension of Period of Stay in Japan a few weeks ago and should be receiving my new visa in middle January. However, due to some unexpected circumstance, I have quit my current job, and my contract will be terminated at the end of January.

Obviously, my current employer would no longer want to vouch for my new visa. But considered that I have already send all necessary documents to Immigration Bureau, does that mean I can still get a new visa, or could my current employer block it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two possible cases, depending on whether the extension (which is not a new visa, by the way) is granted before or after your contract is terminated.

If it is granted before, you are probably safe (but remember that in any case, your status can be revoked if you are out of a job for three months). It could raise eyebrows when you report the termination of your contract soon after your status has been extended, but it is unlikely that they would press the issue further: if you stay too long without a job, they can kick you out anyway.

If you report the termination of your contract before the extension is granted, however, it is likely that they will just deny it.